# The [storyteller-system] Tag Synonym - Inaccurate, but probably irrelevant?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was poking through the tags, looking for things to flag as favorites and I came across [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system). It appears to be aliased to [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness), but that's not accurate: There were three other Storyteller-based games published by White Wolf: [<strike>Aeon</strike> Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(role-playing_game)), [Aberrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberrant), and [Adventure!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure!).

We don't seem to have any questions that cover any of the three, but their existence makes the synonym and it's description inaccurate. **Is it worth fixing?**

Answer (score 4):

It may or may not be worth fixing. Since tagging follows what we need in a practical sense though, it's not possible to tell whether it's important to fix until we actually have questions that show a need to be tagged with [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system).

Historically we had few to no questions that were actually tagged with just [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system); in practice it was (nearly?) always a redundant tag beside [cwod] or somesuch. My guess is that if we ever do have other games in the Storyteller system family, they'll only need game-name tags like [aberrant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aberrant) and won't benefit from being collected together under a family-system tag.

If we have or get questions that would benefit from an independent [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) tag though, or there is a clear and present need to encourage people to use the [storyteller-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storyteller-system) tag itself, we can always detach it from [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness) and make that happen! It's just not really worth it for hypothetical uses, when the practical uses have (as far as I recall) always just been as a synonym for classic WoD anyway.

Comment: *nod* Since those games are getting a second edition soon anyway, we can tag them with the new system tag, whatever it's going to be, and if we need to backfill, we can.